# Show Delivery Time over or under Availability on Products Page

Tags: magento2.3, custom-attributes

I am completely new to magento.
I use Magento 2.3 and I created an attribute `Lieferzeit` under Stores->Attributes->Product and set `visibility` to `yes`.

Further, I set the Attribute to a group in Stores-Attributes-> Attribute Set.

What is the next step here?
I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show your attribute above/below stock availability, You need to copy:

> magento2Root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

In the above file you already have `$_product` object.

at the end of file, put below code to get your attribute:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('lieferzeit'); ?>
    -------OR------
<?php echo $_product->getLieferzeit(); ?>
    -------OR------
<?php echo $_product->getData('lieferzeit'); ?>
```

**Note:**

- Use any one code from above
- I am assuming your attribute code is `lieferzeit`.

Comment: Where do i set `Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront`? in Admin section?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thank you for your answer. I copied the default.phtml in the folder and added `<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('lieferzeit'); ?>`
at the very bottom. Flushed Cache but it doesnt appear in frontend. I am using the Porto Theme if this is important.

Comment: Okay, now i used another code and it worked. Thank you so far. But now i got a new tab with this informations shown.

http://pixelmonkeys.de/screenshot.png

Comment: You need to set `Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront`->` NO`, if you don't want to show on front tab

Comment: Your answer should be comment for given answer. if you need any clarification, put a comment to answer!